# Google cloud out of memory handling large tensors, docker limit?

Tags: tensorflow, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-ml

Training and evaluating big neural network models (tensorflow) on google cloud.

Got the following error when evaluating my model:

```
W  Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[38633472,17] 
W  Ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.45GiB.  See logs for memory state. 
  undefined
```

I think it has to do with the container memory limit.

Any help on that?

Comment: Can you give more details? The container you are using, the model you are trying to run etc.,

Comment: I am not sure what container google cloud is using. I simply run the 'ml-engine jobs submit training' command, I use a pretty big logistic model.

Answer (score 1):

Which [scale tier](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/concepts/training-overview#scale_tiers) and machine type were you using? In case of OOM, you can try to use larger machine in CUSTOM tier.

If you still have the issue, please send us your project number and job id to cloudml-feedback@google.com, so that we can take a close look.

Comment: I tried both BASIC_GPU and CUSTOM tiers. You don't specify the abolute memory of the instances. For some reason I was not able to use the large_complex_model instance, which seems to have the most memory...